# Jquery File Upload: Configuring the maxFileSize and AcceptFileTypes

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, file-upload, blueimp

Beginner: 
I am using the Jquery File upload plugin (backload) from blueimp to create a file uploader and wanted to configure the maxFileSize and Accept File Size options of File upload.

i can either set them up in jquery-fileupload-validate or while initializing the fileupload widget as:

```
$('#fileupload').fileupload({
   maxFileSize: 500000,
   acceptFileTypes: /(\.|\/)(doc|docx?g|png)$/i,
  ....
})
```

I am using MVC4 razor and wanted to make this configurable through a config, so that it can be changed without changing the code.

I have some model properties created and wanted to see the various way i can do it like by creating a config file or if there is a way to use the web config or backload config?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Added appsettings in the web.config 
and added two model properties to get the values in the javascript.

we are also doing server side validations to avoid any security attacks